# A somewhat general question about homeomorphisms.

Tags: general-topology

I have been asked to prove that $(0,1)$ is homeomorphic to $(0,1)$. Seems easy enough. If we assume the order topology an both, along with an identity mapping $f:x\to x$, we can show that both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous.

Similarly, using the identity mapping $f$ and the order topology, we can show that $(0,1)$ is not homeomorphic to $[0,1]$. However, how can we prove that there exists no toplogy and suitable mapping such that $(0,1)$ can be proven to be homeomorphic to $[0,1]$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Well $(0,1)$ and $[0,1]$ have the same cardinality, so there exists a bijection $\Phi:(0,1)\rightarrow[0,1]$. Now, equip $(0,1)$ with any topology and define $U\subset [0,1]$ to be open if and only if $\Phi^{-1}(U)$ is open. Then it can easily be checked that $\Phi$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: A related question. Say I have the identity mapping $f:x\to x$ from $[0,1]$ to $(0,1)$. Obviously $f$ is continuous. Also, for $f^{-1}$, the inverse of every set of the form $(a,b)$ is $(a,b)$, and hence open. In addition to this, the inverse of $[0,r]$ is $(0,r)$, which is also open in $(0,1)$. Hence, is $f^{-1}$ continuous? Have I proved that both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous, and except for a bijection, all conditions for a homeomorphism are satisfied?

Comment: But there is no identity mapping $[0,1]\rightarrow (0,1)$

Comment: Identity mapping from $(0,1)$ to $[0,1]$....embedding, if you like.

Comment: Regardless of the nature of the mapping, is $f^{-1}$ continuous?

Comment: But the inclusion $(0,1)\hookrightarrow [0,1]$ does not have an inverse.